# Thread Management and parallelism with boost::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, parallel-processing, boost-thread

I have some problem with understanding how join_all() function works. I created a boost::thread_group and put some threads on it . After i used join_all() on a thread group. In my understanding it will make program to fully use the CPU threads - all of the threads that can be runned at certain moment -  will be,  rest of them will be waiting for their turn.

Am i right ? 
If i am wrong - how join_all() works ? And how to make thread gruup be executed automatically and in FIFO order ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[join_all()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.threadgroup.join_all) blocks  the issuing thread until all the threads within the group are finished.

The threads are executing as you start them.

Your question is way too fuzzy to know what you really want to know, I suggest reading the top of referred page on how to use the module.

Comment: Thats what i wanted to know. Thank You very much.